# Temporarily store variable in series of pipes dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to pause a series of pipes to store a temporary variable that can be used later on in pipe sequence?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369832/assign-intermediate-output-to-temp-variable-as-part-of-dplyr-pipeline) but I'm not sure that it was doing the same thing I am looking for.

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(Grp = c("Apple","Boy","Cat","Dog","Edgar","Apple","Boy","Cat","Dog","Edgar"),
             a = sample(0:9, 10, replace = T),
             b = sample(0:9, 10, replace = T),
             c = sample(0:9, 10, replace = T),
             d = sample(0:9, 10, replace = T),
             e = sample(0:9, 10, replace = T),
             f = sample(0:9, 10, replace = T),
             g = sample(0:9, 10, replace = T))
```

I am going to convert `df` to long format but, after having done so, I will need to apply the number of rows before the `gather`.

This is what my desired output looks like. In this case, storing the number of rows before the pipe begins would look like:

```
n <- nrow(df)

df %>% 
  gather(var, value, -Grp) %>% 
  mutate(newval = value * n)
# A tibble: 70 x 4
   Grp   var   value newval
   <chr> <chr> <int>  <int>
 1 Apple a         2     20
 2 Boy   a         7     70
 3 Cat   a         4     40
 4 Dog   a         8     80
 5 Edgar a         9     90
 6 Apple a         0      0
 7 Boy   a         5     50
 8 Cat   a         8     80
 9 Dog   a         5     50
10 Edgar a         4     40
# ... with 60 more rows
```

In my real world problem, I have a long chain of pipes and it would be a lot easier if I could perform this action within the pipe structure. I would like to do something that looks like this:

```
df %>% 
  { "n = nrow(.)" } %>% # temporary variable is created here but df is passed on
  gather(var, value, -Grp) %>% 
  mutate(newval = value * n)
```

I could do something like the following, but it seems really sloppy.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(n = nrow(.)) %>% 
  gather(var, value, -Grp, -n) %>% 
  mutate(newval = value * mean(n))
```

Is there a way to do this or perhaps a good workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a code block for a local variable. This would look like

```
df %>% 
{ n = nrow(.)
  gather(., var, value, -Grp) %>% 
  mutate(newval = value * n)
}
```

Notice how we have to pass the `.` to `gather` as well here and the pipe continues inside the block. But you could put other parts afterwards

```
df %>% 
{ n = nrow(.)
  gather(., var, value, -Grp) %>% 
  mutate(newval = value * n)
} %>% 
select(newval)
```

Comment: Nice. Out of curiosity, I assume that code blocks can be nested.

Comment: Sure. Code blocks can be nested. You just need to be careful of what's currently being passed as the `.` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `%>>%` (pipe operator) from `pipeR`

```
library(pipeR)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>>% 
   (~ n  = nrow(.)) %>% 
    gather(., var, value, -Grp) %>%
    mutate(newval = value * n)
# A tibble: 70 x 4
#   Grp   var   value newval
#   <chr> <chr> <int>  <int>
# 1 Apple a         2     20
# 2 Boy   a         7     70
# 3 Cat   a         4     40
# 4 Dog   a         8     80
# 5 Edgar a         9     90
# 6 Apple a         0      0
# 7 Boy   a         5     50
# 8 Cat   a         8     80
# 9 Dog   a         5     50
#10 Edgar a         4     40
# … with 60 more rows
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going in and coming out of the second line? I just looked up the `pipeR` pipe and get the basics now, but I don't see why this works. `df` is being `pipeR` piped into the parentheses so the pipe send `df` only to `.` but I'm lost after that.

Comment: @hmhensen  The `.` in `%>%` syntax is the data output from the `lhs` of the `%>%` for processing on the rhs of pipe.  The `~` is anonymous function call (similar syntax you can find in tidyverse)  to generate an object identifier (`n` ) store it in the environment for later processing.  while the `gather` step is again using the `.` data coming from `df` i.e.the data itself and then the mutate is just dplyr syntax to create a new column

Comment: I'm still not really sure why the `pipeR` pipe works here while the `magrittr` pipe doesn't. How is `df` making it through to the second pipe? Why is `n` not being passed through? With MrFlick's use of brackets, it makes sense to me. I'm not following that part here though since there's only one thing happening in the parentheses. I guess my lack of programming experience is shining through.

Comment: @hmhensen  `n` is available if you check the last step.

Comment: Sorry, I mean why do the objects that comes out of the parentheses include both `df` AND `n`? I see why the `n` is output, but how does `df` get output? Since `df` is acted upon by `nrow` how does it come out of the parentheses intact, too?

Comment: @hmhensen that is the original output (or say the master output coming from the pipe (`.`)) while the second one i.e. nrow(.) is assigned to a new identifier 'n', which we use it.  I think you can also asssign multiple other variables and call it by that identifier

Comment: @hmhensen  Check this `df %>>% 
   (~ n  = nrow(.)) %>>% (~ m = 25) %>% 
     gather(., var, value, -Grp) %>%
     mutate(newval = value * n, newval2 = m)`