# How to find the sum total of a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to get the `sum` of `n` from a `count` table. I'm able to do this with this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  pull(n) %>% 
  sum()
```

Is there a one-line way to do this in base R. The purpose of the value is to add this as a caption on a table like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  kable(caption = "n =  (insert value here")
```

I actually want to count the total of the n because in my real pipe workflow I filter the data frame.

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(vs == 1) %>% 
  count(cyl)

#   cyl  n
# 1   4 10
# 2   6  4
```

In this case, I would like it to be 14 (10+4) which is the sum of `n` and not 32.

Something like this solution: [Temporarily store variable in series of pipes dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064713/temporarily-store-variable-in-series-of-pipes-dplyr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by a simple `sum` and referring to the `n` column within the pipe;

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(vs == 1) %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  kable(caption = paste0("n = ", sum(.$n)))
```

##### n = 14

| cyl | n |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 10 |
| 6 | 4 |

---

If you're counting all the rows, this can be done using `dplyr::tally` as well;

```r
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  kable(caption = paste0("n = ", tally(mtcars)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `nrow` to count the number of rows in data -

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  kable(caption = paste0("n = ", nrow(mtcars)))

#Table: n = 32

#| cyl|  n|
#|---:|--:|
#|   4| 11|
#|   6|  7|
#|   8| 14|
```

Answer (score 1):

We may also use `with`

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  kable(format = "pipe", caption = glue::glue("n = {with(., sum(n))}"))
```

-output

```
Table: n = 32

| cyl|  n|
|---:|--:|
|   4| 11|
|   6|  7|
|   8| 14|
```