# Repeat/duplicate specific row of data frame and append

Tags: r

I would like to duplicate a certain row based on information in a data frame. Prefer a `tidyverse` solution. I'd like to accomplish this without explicitly calling the original data frame in a function.

Here's a toy example.

```
data.frame(var1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
           var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
           val = c(21, 31, 54, 65, 76))
  var1 var2 val
1    A    1  21
2    A    2  31
3    A    3  54
4    B    4  65
5    B    5  76
```

All the solutions I've found so far require the user to input the desired row index. I'd like to find a way of doing it programmatically. In this case, I would like to duplicate the row where `var1` is "A" with the highest value of `var2` for "A" and append to the original data frame. The expected output is

```
  var1 var2 val
1    A    1  21
2    A    2  31
3    A    3  54
4    B    4  65
5    B    5  76
6    A    3  54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the row that you want to duplicate and add it to original dataframe :

```
library(dplyr)

var1_variable <- 'A'
df %>%
  filter(var1 == var1_variable) %>%
  slice_max(var2, n = 1) %>%
  #For dplyr < 1.0.0
  #slice(which.max(var2)) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .)

#  var1 var2 val
#1    A    1  21
#2    A    2  31
#3    A    3  54
#4    B    4  65
#5    B    5  76
#6    A    3  54
```

In base R, that can be done as :

```
df1 <- subset(df, var1 == var1_variable)
rbind(df, df1[which.max(df1$var2), ])
```

---

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40381706/3962914) we can save the previous work in a temporary variable and then bind rows so that we don't break the chain and don't bind the original dataframe `df`.

```
df %>%
  #Previous list of commands
  {
    {. -> temp} %>%
      filter(var1 == var1_variable) %>%
      slice_max(var2, n = 1) %>%
      bind_rows(temp)
  }
```

Comment: I actually came to the same conclusion, but for better or worse, I have a chain of previous functions applied to the original data and I am trying not to duplicate that work within the bind_rows function. I looked for a way to call the input data frame in bind_rows twice but no luck.

Comment: Something like `df %>% bind_rows(., . %>% slice(3))`.

Comment: I don't completely understand but you can break the chain into two parts? Store all the changes above this in `df1`, use the above code and `bind_rows`  to `df1` ?

Comment: I could. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without breaking it up.

Comment: I think the updated answer might help doing this without breaking the chain.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Creating a temporary variable did it.

Answer (score 3):

A variation using dplyr. Find the `max` by group, filter for `var1` and append.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  filter(var2 == max(var2), 
         var1 == "A") %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)

  var1 var2 val
1    A    1  21
2    A    2  31
3    A    3  54
4    B    4  65
5    B    5  76
6    A    3  54
```

Comment: `df1` is a copy-paste error :) I always use `df1` for data frame names in my own code, changed it to `df` here but forgot the second one.

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can use `rbind` and `subset` to *append the row(s) where `var1 == "A"` with the highest value of `var2` to the original data frame*.

```
rbind(x, subset(x[x$var1 == "A",], var2 == max(var2)))
#   var1 var2 val
#1     A    1  21
#2     A    2  31
#3     A    3  54
#4     B    4  65
#5     B    5  76
#31    A    3  54
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
           var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
           val = c(21, 31, 54, 65, 76))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     uncount(replace(rep(1, n()), match(max(val[var1 == 'A']), val), 2)) %>% 
     as_tibble
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  var1   var2   val
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1    21
#2 A         2    31
#3 A         3    54
#4 A         3    54
#5 B         4    65
#6 B         5    76
```