# Renaming row values in gt() tables

Tags: r, gt

I'm trying to remove string from at gt() table, but without success.
In my table I want multiple column names/titles covering two columns named "Day 0", "Day 4", "Day 10", "Day 17" and sub columns named "mean" and "se". Probably easier to understand when looking at the data.

What I want right now is to remove the "day 0" (or e.g. "day 4") from the sub column.
Any suggestions?

My code:

```
library(gt)

gt(mean_se)%>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 0", columns = matches("0")) %>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 4", columns = matches("4")) %>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 10", columns = matches("10")) %>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 17", columns = matches("17")) %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("Biogenic volatile organic compound emissions"))
  
  # str_remove(mean_se, "day 0")
  # rename("mean"=="mean day 0")
```

Here's the data:

```
mean_se <- structure(list(mass = c("i.x33.031", "i.x35.034", "i.x36.017", 
"i.x39.959", "i.x40.023"), `mean day 0` = c("241.82", "0.36", 
"1.78", "0.2", "1.82"), `se day 0` = c("241.82", "0.36", "1.78", 
"0.2", "1.82"), `mean day 4` = c("32.94", "0.14", "0", "0", "1.74"
), `se day 4` = c("32.94", "0.14", "0", "0", "1.74"), `mean day 10` = c("266.28", 
"0.6", "0", "0", "1.58"), `se day 10` = c("266.28", "0.6", "0", 
"0", "1.58"), `mean day 17` = c("451.4", "0.48", "0", "0", "2.94"
), `se day 17` = c("451.4", "0.48", "0", "0", "2.94")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this seems tedious but you could re-label the columns one by one like this: `gt(mean_se) %>% cols_label("mean day 0" = "mean")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is with `cols_label`. This function accepts individuals arguments to rename a specific column, for example `"mean day 0" = "mean"`. But it's a lot of work to type all those out. Instead, we can use `.list =` and provide a named list of all the columns we want to rename.

We can just repeat `"mean"` and `"se"` the appropriate number of times and name that character vector with the column names:

```
setNames(rep(c("mean","se"),(ncol(mean_se)-1)/2),names(mean_se)[-1])
# mean day 0    se day 0  mean day 4    se day 4 mean day 10   se day 10 mean day 17   se day 17 
#     "mean"        "se"      "mean"        "se"      "mean"        "se"      "mean"        "se"
```

To keep the order correct, we can use `cols_move`.

```
gt(mean_se)%>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 0", columns = matches("0")) %>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 4", columns = matches("4")) %>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 10", columns = matches("10")) %>%
  tab_spanner(label = "Day 17", columns = matches("17")) %>%
  cols_label(.list = setNames(rep(c("mean","se"),(ncol(mean_se)-1)/2),
                              names(mean_se)[-1])) %>%
  cols_move(columns = names(mean_se)[-1], after = names(mean_se)[1]) %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("Biogenic volatile organic compound emissions"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ian Campbell, it works quite well! However now Day 10 is suddenly before Day 4? I don't exactly understand how the setNames list works, but it saves me some time for sure.

Comment: Nice catch, I have edited my answer to include a call to `cols_move` which forces the order.

Comment: Looking for this exact solution but if you use 'select' and change the number of columns 'names()' doesn't work. Looks like gt doesn't allow 'names(.)' to function inside it. I could add a variable outside the pipe but was wondering if there is a solution inside the pipe. Thanks

Comment: @seansteele The typical solution to this problem is to pipe the data into `{}` and then assign `.` to a temporary variable that exists within `{}` but not the global environment. See this Q&A for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369832/assign-intermediate-output-to-temp-variable-as-part-of-dplyr-pipeline

Comment: Thanks! I had tried some of those solutions  from other thread but they did pass the temp variable to gt. The `pipeR` solution worked though!